# How to fix 'Bareword found' issue in perl eval()

Tags: regex, perl, eval

The following code returns "Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "*,out" (Missing operator before out?)"

```
$val = 0;
$name = "abc";
$myStr = '$val = ($name =~ in.*,out [)';
eval($myStr);
```

As per my understanding, I can resolve this issue by wrapping "in.*,out [" block with '//'s.

But that "in.*,out [" can be varied. (eg: user inputs). and users may miss giving '//'s. therefore, is there any other way to handle this issue.? (eg : return 0 if eval() is trying to return that 'Bareword found where ...')

Comment: Note that the "string `eval`" is generally a terrible idea, and dddangerous. It allows _arbitrary_  code to run; even without any bad intent that can break things badly. Is it certain that there is no other way?  Almost always there is.

Comment: The error message you show implies that you are running that (dangerous) code without warnings enabled?  (There'd be different messages with `use warnings;`.) That, altogether, is just asking for trouble.  Just a well intended warning.

Comment: What is the purpose of you using eval there?

Comment: The purpose is to execute $myStr. [ I have a given pattern (in here, it is "in.*,out [" ) and I'm doing a regex match with $name. after that i store the result in $val. ]

Comment: @yasaramalshan "_The purpose is to execute `$myStr`_"  -- the question is, why do you need to do that?  It seems that you can have normal code, `my $val = ($name =~ /$input/);`, and when you take user's input (earlier in the program presumably) assign it to `$input`.  Why can you not just do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The magic of (string) [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval) -- and the danger -- is that it turns a heap of dummy characters into *code*, compiles and runs it.  So can one then use `'$x = ,hi'`?  Well, no, of course, when that string is considered code then that's a loose comma operator there, a syntax eror; and a "bareword" `hi`.<sup>†</sup> The string must yield valid code

> In a string eval, the value of the expression (which is itself determined within scalar context) is first parsed, and if there were no errors, executed as a block within the lexical context of the current Perl program.

So that string in the question as it stands would be just (badly) invalid code, which won't compile, period.  If the `in.*,out [` part of the string is in quotes of some sort, then that is legitimate and the [`=~` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators) will take it as a pattern and you have a regex.  But then of course why not use regex's normal pattern delimiters, like `//` (or `m{}`, etc).

And whichever way that string gets acquired it'll be in a variable, no? So you can have `/$input/` in the `eval` and populate that `$input` beforehand.

But, above all, are you certain that there is no other way? There always is.  The string-`eval` is complex and tricky and hard to use right and nigh impossible to justify -- and dangerous.  It runs *arbitrary* code!  That can break things badly even without any bad intent.

I'd strongly suggest to consider other solutions.  Also, it is unclear why there'd be need for `eval` in the first place -- as you only need the regex pattern as user input (not code) you can have that very regex in normal code with a pattern in a variable, which is populated earlier when the user input is supplied. (Note that taking a pattern from the user may lead to trouble as well.)

---

<sup>†</sup> A problem if you're into `warnings`, and we all are.

Answer (score 2):

The following isn't valid Perl code:

```perl
$val = ($name =~ in.*,out [)
```

You want the following:

```perl
$val = $name =~ /in.*,out \[/
```

(The parens weren't harmful, but didn't help either.)

If the pattern is user-supplied, you can use the following:

```perl
$val = $name =~ /$pattern/
```

(No `eval EXPR` needed!)

Note from the correction that the pattern in the question isn't correct. You can catch such errors using `eval BLOCK`

```perl
eval { $val = $name =~ /$pattern/ };
die("Bad pattern \"$pattern\" provided: $@") if $@;
```

A note about user-provided patterns: The above won't let the user execute arbitrary code, but it won't protect you from patterns that would take longer than the lifespan of the universe to complete.